# Implementing a list of evaluation contexts?

Tags: kframework

I'm attempting to implement an evaluation stack as a list of KItems.

I have a rule that adds evaluation contexts into the stack:

```
rule <k> X:KVar V:Val ~> E => !DOSOMETHING! </k>
     <stack> ES => E ~> ES </stack>
```

However, I encounter a bug when adding an empty E to the stack.

I attempted to extend KItem with a constructor:

```
syntax KItem ::= "MyContext" KItem
```

However, this causes rules of the form

```
rule <k> !DOSOMETHING! => !V:KVar ~> E </k>
     <stack> MyContext E ~> ES => ES </stack>
```

to fail pattern matching.

Is there a correct way of implementing a stack of evaluation contexts like I'm trying to do?

EDIT:

```
  syntax Exp ::= Int | KVar | Exp "+" Exp [seqstrict(1,2), left]
               | "!DOSOMETHING!"
               | "(" Exp ")"       [bracket]

  syntax KResult ::= Int

  configuration 
      <T>
        <k> $PGM:Exp </k>
        <stack> .K </stack>
      </T>

  syntax KItem ::= "MyContext" KItem

  rule I1:Int + I2:Int => I1 +Int I2
  
  rule <k> X:KVar + V ~> E:KItem => !DOSOMETHING! </k>
       <stack> ES => MyContext E ~> ES </stack>
  rule <k> V + X:KVar ~> E:KItem => !DOSOMETHING! </k>
       <stack> ES => MyContext E ~> ES </stack>
  rule <k> !DOSOMETHING! => 0 ~> E </k>
       <stack> MyContext E:KItem ~> ES => ES </stack>
```

would immediately get stuck on a file:

```
1 + X + 3 + X + 5
```

If we remove the `MyContext`,

```
  rule <k> X:KVar + V ~> E:KItem => !DOSOMETHING! </k>
       <stack> ES => E ~> ES </stack>
  rule <k> V + X:KVar ~> E:KItem => !DOSOMETHING! </k>
       <stack> ES => E ~> ES </stack>       
  rule <k> !DOSOMETHING! => 0 ~> E </k>
       <stack> E:KItem ~> ES => ES </stack>
```

the semantics gets stuck with `x + 1`.

I suspect I'm actually talking about different issues here. But how does one pattern match the evaluation context correctly?

Comment: It's not possible to determine the cause of this problem from the partial example you provided. Please make sure when you are asking for help that the code you provide is self contained enough for answerers to be able to actually run a program that reproduces the issue.

Comment: sorry. I added an edit with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your k cell contains a single KItem, which is the addition expression, but the only rules that match addition at the top of the k cell require a second KItem to be present and thus do not apply if there is only one KItem. Did you mean to match a variable of sort K instead? The k cell normally contains a term of sort K, which is a sort representing a cons list of KItem of which ~> is the concatenation operator and .K is the list unit. For convenience, the user can write terms of sort K as if it is an associative list so long as they don't actually match a term of sort K on top of another term, but the rules that you wrote only match a list with exactly two elements. If you intend for E to match the tail of the list, you need to change the sort of E to K.

Comment: Would the type of evaluation contexts, e.g. in `1 ~> #freezer_+__ ...`, everything after the `#freezer` be of sort `K`?

Comment: Also, if the evaluation context were empty, would `X ~> E` match anything?

Comment: If you have some sequence of KItems 1 ~> 2~> 3 ~> ... ~> .K, 1, 2, and 3 are KItems, and .K, 3 ~> ... ~> .K, 2 ~> 3 ~> ... ~> .K, and 1 ~> 2 ~> 3 ... ~> .K are sort K.

Comment: If you have a sequence X ~> .K, then E would match .K. when you write X by itself where a term of sort K is expected, it implicitly means X ~> .K, unless you have a ... On the rhs of the k cell, in which case it means X ~> _

Comment: since `.K` is the empty list, is it possible to have a list of empty contexts?

Comment: It is possible to create a list where the element sort is K, but you would probably have to construct it by means of another sort with a single constructor with one child of sort K